# Map redundancy in Cassandra

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

**Input**: Tabular data files: each file has variable number of columns, and those column names may be unique to the file and/or shared between other files (unknown beforehand). This data is not expected to change, so inserts will be frequent but updates will be rare. Columns and their assiated values may be textual or numeric.

**Requested Capability**: Be able to query by identity or range to retrieve the row(s) of data given a column name and value.

**Data Model**: In `CQL` I can model using a single table representing a specific cell value of a file (in this case textual, but a similar table can be constructed for numeric data)

```
create table mytable(
    colname text,
    value text,
    filename text,
    rowid int,
    data map<text,text>,
    primary key (colname , value, filename, rowid)#partitioning on colname may not be ideal here, but will be dealt with in ways unrelated to this question
);
```

For example, the contents of one file could be:

```
A   B   C   D   E
i1  i2  i3  i4  i5
```

The insert would be:

```
insert into mytable(colname, value, data, filename, rowid) values ('A', 'i1', {'A':'i1', 'B':'i2', 'C':'i3', 'D':'i4', 'E':'i5', 'F':'i5'}, 'F1', 1);
insert into mytable(colname, value, data, filename, rowid) values ('B', 'i2', {'A':'i1', 'B':'i2', 'C':'i3', 'D':'i4', 'E':'i5', 'F':'i5'}, 'F1', 2);
insert into mytable(colname, value, data, filename, rowid) values ('C', 'i3', {'A':'i1', 'B':'i2', 'C':'i3', 'D':'i4', 'E':'i5', 'F':'i5'}, 'F1', 3);
insert into mytable(colname, value, data, filename, rowid) values ('D', 'i4', {'A':'i1', 'B':'i2', 'C':'i3', 'D':'i4', 'E':'i5', 'F':'i5'}, 'F1', 4);
insert into mytable(colname, value, data, filename, rowid) values ('E', 'i5', {'A':'i1', 'B':'i2', 'C':'i3', 'D':'i4', 'E':'i5', 'F':'i5'}, 'F1', 5);
...

SELECT data from mytable where colname=? and value=?
```

**Problem:** We do have data storage constraints - in this model the data value is identical for each column value of a row, resulting in lots of excessive data duplication (this is a simplistic example but the number of columns could be upwards of 100's - meaning the map can be duplicated hundreds of times).

**Question:** Is there any way in Cassandra to avoid this type of data duplication *without having to create/query a second table* (for example via a pointer to the data or somehow define the map as distinct)? Or alternatively, a different way to model the data with the same query capability and result?

Comment: Have you considered using Solr which makes this problem pretty straight forward to solve?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Sreekar Will look into it...in particular the performance of Solr with textual or numeric data (our data may be either, and we are looking for efficient range queries on the latter)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be surprised if your design benefits from C* built-it compression, your storage requirements may be well under your expectations.

By the way, if you want a completely different model you can try:

- One table for each column of your input data
- Each table has a partition key that is the value you're looking for

Something along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE colname_A (
    value text,
    data map<text,text>,
    ...,
    PRYMARY KEY (value)
);

CREATE TABLE colname_B (
    value text,
    data map<text,text>,
    ...,
    PRYMARY KEY (value)
);
....
CREATE TABLE colname_xxx (...);
```

You can then select your data by issuing:

```
SELECT * FROM colname_A WHERE value = 'i5';
SELECT * FROM colname_A WHERE value IN ('i4', 'i5')
```

Be careful with queries with the `IN` clausole in the partition key because you want to avoid problems like [this](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/) when you keep loading data into your cluster.

This model organizes data in a different manner and benefits from inter-column data duplication instead of inter-row data duplication. If you have *unbalanced* columns (eg lot of records in some columns) the compression offered by this data organization could be a big win.

Comment: Thank you for those ideas. I had considered a model similar to the one you describe, but it is not entirely clear to me how this would solve my initial problems of a) bloating from data duplication and b) requirement to pull out row data from a single query (unless `data` here is referring to row values)? For what its worth, the number of rows in these files is several times greater than the number of columns.

Comment: The fact that you have more rows than columns seems quite normal. You should chose the model based on how your data is organized, or stick with the model that gives you better compression ratio. **a)** You should try to load a bunch of data before worrying about data duplication. **b)** I don't understand what you mean, is your requirement to extract the map field, is it?

Comment: Nailed it with **a**. Disk usage between alternative models shows that with or without data duplication the disk usage is very similar (certainly surprised me). If you include that point (along with the previous sentence about modelling for data organization) in your answer I will mark this as solved.

Comment: @copeg Disk usage or compression factor? Disk usage could tell you nothing... You should check the compression ratio of the CFs with `nodetool cfstats`. Did you perform flush and compaction when finished loading data?

Comment: Flush yes, compaction no (but now I will), and will check compression factors

Comment: @copeg: any news on that?

Comment: sorry for the delay. For a variety of reasons, I was forced to move ahead with my original data model. The querying requirement in this model far surpassed the data duplication issue in my original question.